# fixing slider on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add slider to run on my website but it is trowing this error preventing it from running.

[image]

this is link of the webstie 
http://victoryauctions.net/
can anyone help me

Comment: Please provide more than just a screenshot to describe the problem you are encountering. Similarly, please tell us what you have tried to do to fix your problem?

Comment: I see on your side that you have not commented properly some code. Maybe this will break the rest of your code.

Comment: Additionally you have also commented some javascript that probably is required for you slider to work properly. What I see seems a css problem.

Comment: @Franco What's the different between your *fix*? You can have `------->` as closing tag of comment

Comment: @Justinas, this is not a fix, I had a look at the site script and I see some javascript commented. It was just an observation.

Comment: are you find the problem sir ? @Justinas

Answer (score 1):

Remove `max-height: 164px` from `.fetrhgt` and `.clashgt` (maybe it should be `min-height`?

Comment: not working sit